# Left shift << of float variables

Tags: c

I want to multiply num with scale parameter.Here num and scale are floating variables .I am planning to use binary operator that is left shift  << .
PFB the logic what I want to modify for optimization purpose .This is a part of code.Which will give some performance after modifications.

My hardware is very expensive with multiplication operation .My code is doing this multiplication though out image that is height*width time .So I want to avoid this by shift operator

```
typedef float float32_t;
float32_t scale = 64.0 ;
float32_t num = 1.5f ;
num = num *scale ;
```

I want to modify like :

```
//float32_t scale = 64.0 ; //Left shift for performance benefits
float32_t num = 1.5f ;
num = num << 6  ;
```

But I am getting below error :

```
error: invalid operands of types 'float32_t {aka float}' and 'float32_t {aka float}' to binary 'operator<<' float32_t num = num << 6  ;
```

There is one way to modify the arguments type in function itself .But I don't want to modify the prototype of function for this change .
Can any one tell me the solution for this .

Comment: C or C++? Pick _one_.

Comment: _"I am planning to use binary operator that is left shift <<"_ Why?

Comment: for some performance benefits in timing

Comment: This doesn't even make sense , you cannot operate on a variable in the same line that you define it. `float32_t num = num * scale;` causes undefined behaviour because `num` is uninitialized when `num * scale` is being computed.

Comment: Your compiler is cleverer than you, just write `*64` and let it do its job. Otherwise, there are functions like `ldexp`, `scalbn`.

Comment: @studinstru: What "performance benefits" do you anticipate achieving? It sounds like you're wildly guessing.

Comment: My hardware is very expensive with multiplication operation .My code is doing this multiplication though out image that is height*width time .SO I want to avoid this by shift operator .

Answer (score 8):

In C the operands of `<<` and `>>` operator must be of integer type.

#### C11: 6.5 Expressions (p4):

> Some operators (the unary operator `~`, and the binary operators `<<`, `>>`, `&`, `^`, and `|`, collectively described as **bitwise operators**) **are required to have operands that have integer type**.[...]

Note that in

```
float32_t num = num *scale ;
```

`num` is not initialized and its value is unspecified and may result in undefined behavior.

Comment: Just to be precise, chapter `6.5.7`, _Bitwise shift operators_. Paragraph 2 :-)

Answer (score 5):

The error is telling you that your decision to use a bitwise shift is non-sensical.

Stick with the multiplication operator.

Answer (score 3):

Shifting floating point values doesn't make any sense. Even if you forced the compiler to generate code that shifts the bits of the floating point value the result would definitely not be equivalent to multiplication. Bits in floating point numbers aren't generally organized like integers.

If there's any optimization that your compiler can do to make a multiplication by a power of two faster the compiler will figure it out for you.

If your complier is terrible and can't figure out the optimization the standard function you're looking for is called `ldexp`. It multiplies a floating point value by a power of two. But if your code is ever running on a machine where `FLT_RADIX` isn't 2 (very uncommon), `ldexp` will probably be a bad idea, so don't do this unless you can show it's strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

A bitwise shift of a floating-point value makes no sense.

If you want to multiply a floating point number by 2<sup>n</sup>, to get the same numeric effect as shifting an integer by `n` bits, there's a library function for that:

```
#include <cmath>                           // C++, <math.h> in C
float32_t scaled_num = std::ldexp(num, 6); // C++, ldexpf in C (assuming `float32_t` is `float`)
```